# Why python statement `if something is None` works much quicker than `if not something`?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I came across this question when writing a fibonacci function. To make it quicker, I use a dictionary named cache to store the numbers that already have been calculated. So I wrote

```
def fib(n, cache=None):
    if not cache:
        cache = {}
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    if n==0 or n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        cache[n] = fib(n-1, cache) + fib(n-2, cache)
    return cache[n]

def fib_run(n):
    start = time.time()
    fib(n)
    end = time.time()
    print("fib_run cost: {}".format(end-start))
```

And I call`fib_run(30)`, the output is `fib_run cost: 0.8419640064239502`, it just as slow as the function without a cache.
But when I change `if not cache:` into `if cache is None:` in the function `fib2`, it works much quicker.

```
def fib2(n, cache=None):
    if cache is None:
        cache = {}
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    if n==0 or n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        cache[n] = fib2(n-1, cache) + fib2(n-2, cache)
    return cache[n]

def fib2_run(n):
    start = time.time()
    fib2(n)
    end = time.time()
    print("fib_run cost: {}".format(end-start))

>>> fib2_run(30)
fib2_run cost: 2.6226043701171875e-05
```

I wonder why there is such a great difference between the two methods(I thought they were just the same in the early days). Thank you.

Comment: `cache is None` is identity check. `not cache` is emptiness check for dictionary. Those are two different operations under the hood.

Comment: you mean the emptiness check costs much more time? could you tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here isn't the performance of `is None` vs `not cache`, instead, it's that `if cache is None` is `True` only during the first invocation of `fib2` while `if not cache` is `True` even if `cache == {}` for `fib`. 'Empty' collections evaluate to `False` therefore `not` an empty collection will be `True`:

```
>>> not {}
True
```

So you're doing extra work (assigning cache to `{}`) even in the cases where `cache` *already* is equal to `{}`.

In general, these operations are pretty similar in performance, one is a simple identity check while the other is based on the boolness of the value (which, for dictionaries, is based on the result of `__len__` if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the cache is always empty! No wonder you get the same timing as the function without a cache. All you need is a print to see what happens.

```
if not cache:
#if cache is None:
    print(n, "No cache!")
    cache = {}
```

As explained above, empty collections evaluate to false. In the recursive call, `if not cache` is always true, you create a new dict, which you send a level below, which is again evaluated false and so on. There is never a single entry in the cache.

(Doing extra work even in the cases where cache already is equal to {}, as mentioned above, is one time operation. Shouldn't cost anything for bigger n)